# Does local additivity imply local linearity?

Tags: linear-transformations, functional-equations

Suppose $D$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $0\in D$ and $-a\in D$ whenever $a\in D$.

Suppose $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(0)=0$, $f(-a)=-f(a)$ and $f(a)>f(a')$ whenever $a>a'$.

Suppose also that there exist $x,y\in D$ such that $x>y>0$, $x+y\in D$ and  $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

Do the above imply $f(x)=\alpha x$ and $f(y)=\alpha y$ for some $\alpha>0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it does.

Take $D=\{(-1-e),-e,-1,0,1,e,1+e\}$

f(1)=1 , f(e)=2e and f(1+e)=1+2e and such that f(-x)=-f(x).

It should satisfy all your conditions, but not the conclusion. (By the way it's not important that I took an irrational number: I just think it makes things a little bit cleaner.)

Comment: Not really: this has nothing to do with integers. Just take f(x) to be 2x and f(y) to be y and finally f(x+y)=2x+y and you have same kind of problem. It's simply the fact that you have too much "freedom" for your function to impose linearity on it. I just chose e, because it's a bit more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Keen's answer is excellent but here is an example that shows that $f$ need not really be 'fine-tuned' to $D$:

Just take $f$ the function defined by $f(d) = d^3$ for all $d \in D$ and let $D$ be any set containg $y = 0$ and $x = 1$.

The point is: your restrictions dictate that $f$ is a monotonously increasing, odd function but not much more. There are a lot of such functions, $d \mapsto d^3$ is just the simplest non-linear one.

Now once you have the function the condition of there just being ONE pair $(x, y)$ satisfying $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ is really putting very little restrictions. Of course, the more such pairs $(x, y)$ you want to exist, the harder it becomes to find an $f$.

In an extreme case: when you demand $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for ALL $x, y$ in $D$ we do need that $f$ is linear when $D$ consists only of rational numbers. An interesting intermediate question is what happens in the case where you demand that for every $x \in D$ there is an $y \neq 0$ in $D$ such that $f(x +y) = f(x) + f(y)$.

Comment: Thanks. Your last two requirements on $D$ would probably imply that $D$ is infinite though, correct?

Comment: No, it only would imply $D$ infinite if you insist that $f$ takes values in $D$ as well. But you wrote $f:D \to \mathbb{R}$ so you can just take $f$ to be any linear function and restrict it to a subset $D$ of $\mathbb{R}$ as small as you like. It will still satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ only it will map elements of $D$ to elements of a finite subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$ that will not be entirely contained inside $D$ (unless of course you map everything to zero).